How to find a referential integrity constraint via sp_fkeys?
I am trying to drop a table:
drop table if exists bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary;
go

But there is an FK constraint on it:

Could not drop object 'bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.

I have tried to identify the constraint but have not been able to find it via sp_fkeys.
Each of the following four invocations on sp_fkeys was attempted: but turned up empty:
exec sp_fkeys 'bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary'
exec sp_fkeys 'LawAggregatedPipelineSummary'
exec sp_fkeys @pktable_name = 'bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary'
exec sp_fkeys @pktable_name = 'LawAggregatedPipelineSummary'


I'm impressed you managed to find like the most obsolete way of finding system view information in like 3 questions in a row. Do you Google this info or how do you go about :)

@siggemannen  Yea that was real fun.. I had the misfortune of happening firstly on comments that all of the sp_* were deprecated.  So that sent me on that INFORMATION_SCHEMA wild goose chase.  Then I had seen various sp_* suggestions - and latched on to the wrong ones initially.  Life is an adventure.

Use the proper schema views, eg
select name ForeignKeyName, object_schema_name(parent_object_id) SchemaName, object_name(parent_object_id) TableName
from sys.foreign_keys
where referenced_object_id = object_id('bronze.LawAggregatedPipelineSummary')


@WestCoastProjects - this looks a lot like the query that was provided in a comment on your other question. Why did that one not work for you?
